# Upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 fails

Tags: upgrade, dependencies

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.5 to 20.04. I have used `ppa-purge` to remove all third party PPAs, however I am still getting an error:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
```

When I check `main.log` the only error I see is:

```
2020-10-11 11:55:07,488 INFO installing python-is-python2 because python-minimal was installed
2020-10-11 11:55:07,488 DEBUG Installing 'python-is-python2' (python-minimal was installed on the system)
2020-10-11 11:55:07,582 INFO removing python-minimal because python-is-python2 is being installed
2020-10-11 11:55:07,582 DEBUG Removing 'python-minimal' (python-is-python2 is being installed on the system)
2020-10-11 11:55:07,582 INFO failed to remove python-minimal
2020-10-11 11:55:07,830 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'
```

When I look at `apt.log` I can see a lot of broken packages, but I am not sure how to correctly resolve them without screwing up the system.

```
Broken python-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython-all-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
Broken python2-dev:amd64 Breaks on python-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK Ib > (< 2.7.15-2)
Broken libpython2-dev:amd64 Breaks on libpython-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK > (< 2.7.15-2)
Broken libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 Depends on python-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR >
Broken python2-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython2-dev:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
Broken libboost-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii mR >
Broken libpython-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython2-dev:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
Broken libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 Depends on python-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR >
Broken python-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython-all-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
Broken libboost-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii mR >
Broken libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 Depends on python-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR >
Broken python-dev:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR > (= 2.7.15~rc1-1)
Broken libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 Depends on python-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR >
Broken libboost-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii mR >
Broken libboost1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii mK >
Broken libboost-python1.71-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.71-dev:amd64 < none | 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @un uH > (= 1.71.0-6ubuntu6)
Broken libboost-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python1.71-dev:amd64 < none | 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @un uH >
Broken libboost-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1.0ubuntu1 | 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 @ii umR >
Broken dpkg:amd64 Breaks on libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 < 1.6.12ubuntu0.1 @ii mK > (< 1.7~b)
Broken libqt5core5a:amd64 Breaks on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 4:4.8.7+dfsg-20~)
Broken libgcc1:amd64 Conflicts on libgcc1:i386 < 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 -> 1:10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libuno-sal3:amd64 Breaks on uno-libs3:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 @ii mK >
Broken libboost1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK >
Broken libpython2-stdlib:amd64 Breaks on libpython-stdlib:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
Broken python2-minimal:amd64 Breaks on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
Broken libboost-system1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-system1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libqtdbus4:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqtgui4:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 Breaks on gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu1.3 @ii mK > (< 3.30.1.2-2~)
Broken libqt4-declarative:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-xml:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libboost-serialization1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-serialization1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken qt-at-spi:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8~)
Broken libldb2:amd64 Breaks on libldb1:amd64 < 2:1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1 @ii mK > (< 2:2~)
Broken libboost-thread1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-thread1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-chrono1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-chrono1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-atomic1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-atomic1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-date-time1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-date-time1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libqt4-network:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-script:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-sql:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libboost-filesystem1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-filesystem1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-regex1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-regex1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-test1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-test1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-context1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-context1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-mpi1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libtinyxml2-6a:amd64 Conflicts on libtinyxml2-6:amd64 < 6.0.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK >
Broken libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64 Depends on libqt4-sql:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken python3-mutagen:amd64 Breaks on python-mutagen:amd64 < 1.38-1 @ii mK > (< 1.44.0-1)
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:i386 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >
Broken libpython2-dev:amd64 Breaks on libpython-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
Broken libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libboost-python1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-stacktrace1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-stacktrace1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-container1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-container1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-program-options1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-program-options1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libqt4-dbus:amd64 Depends on libqtdbus4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libboost-numpy1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-numpy1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK >
Broken libboost-graph-parallel1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-graph-parallel1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost1.71-tools-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.65-tools-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK >
Broken libboost-graph1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-graph1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken python2-dev:amd64 Breaks on python-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK Ib > (< 2.7.15-2)
Broken libboost-exception1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-exception1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi-python1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libqt4-designer:amd64 Depends on libqt4-script:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libboost-coroutine1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-coroutine1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-locale1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-locale1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libhfstospell10:amd64 Conflicts on libhfstospell:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libboost-timer1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-timer1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-wave1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-wave1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken python-keyring:amd64 Breaks on python-keyrings.alt:amd64 < 3.0-1 @ii mK > (< 3.1)
Broken libboost-log1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-log1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-random1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-random1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-math1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-math1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-fiber1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-fiber1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-iostreams1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-iostreams1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost-type-erasure1.71-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-type-erasure1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libqt4-qt3support:amd64 Depends on libqt4-designer:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-svg:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-help:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libavcodec-extra58:amd64 Conflicts on libavcodec58:i386 < none -> 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uN >
Broken qdbus:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.71.0:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi-python1.65.1:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libqt4-scripttools:amd64 Depends on libqt4-script:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken fwupdate:amd64 Breaks on fwupdate-signed:amd64 < 12-7~ubuntu18.04.3 @ii mK >
Broken fwupdate:amd64 Breaks on libfwup1:amd64 < 12-3bionic2 @ii mK > (< 12-5)
Broken libqt4-test:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken python-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb1:amd64 < 2:1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1 @ii mR > (= 2:1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken libqt4-dev:amd64 Depends on libqt4-dbus:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libgtk2-trayicon-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 Depends on libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken qt4-linguist-tools:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-opengl:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libboost-signals1.65-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gR > (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5)
Broken libqt4-dev-bin:amd64 Depends on libqt4-qt3support:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken python-tdb:amd64 Depends on libtdb1:amd64 < 1.3.15-2 -> 1.4.2-3build1 @ii umU > (= 1.3.15-2)
Broken libgtk2-notify-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libqtassistantclient4:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8.1)
Broken python-samba:amd64 Depends on python-ldb:amd64 < 2:1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1 @ii mR > (>= 1.1.2~)
Broken libebook-1.2-19:amd64 Depends on libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 @ii mR > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken libcupsppdc1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libcupscgi1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libedata-cal-1.2-28:amd64 Depends on libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken libsnmp30:amd64 Depends on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)
Broken python-qt4:amd64 Depends on libqt4-dbus:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8.0-1~)
Broken libapt-inst2.0:amd64 Depends on libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 < 1.6.12ubuntu0.1 @ii mR > (>= 1.1~exp9)
Broken libpango1.0-0:amd64 Depends on libpango-1.0-0:amd64 < 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 -> 1.44.7-2ubuntu4 @ii umU > (= 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken libpolkit-backend-1-0:amd64 Depends on libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64 < 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5 -> 0.105-26ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5)
Broken libcupsmime1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libboost-signals-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-signals1.65-dev:amd64 < 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 @ii gR >
Broken python-pip:amd64 Depends on python-pip-whl:amd64 < 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.3 -> 20.0.2-5ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.3)
Broken libavformat58:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken libchromaprint1:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libavfilter7:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken libavdevice58:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken libquicktime2:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken vlc-plugin-base:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.2)
Broken vlc-plugin-video-output:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.2)
Broken mplayer:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.2)
Broken mpv:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.2)
Broken phonon4qt5-backend-vlc:amd64 Depends on vlc-plugin-base:amd64 < 3.0.8-0ubuntu18.04.1 | 3.0.9.2-1 @ii umR >
Broken ffmpeg:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken libkf5filemetadata-bin:amd64 Depends on libavformat58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.1)
Broken libffmpegthumbnailer4v5:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libmpv1:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.2)
Broken libchromaprint-tools:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken mencoder:amd64 Depends on mplayer:amd64 < none | 2:1.3.0-8build5 @un uH >
Broken libfaudio0:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.2)
Broken vlc:amd64 Depends on vlc-plugin-base:amd64 < 3.0.8-0ubuntu18.04.1 | 3.0.9.2-1 @ii umR > (= 3.0.9.2-1)
Broken libavcodec-extra:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-extra58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken libopencv-videoio4.2:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libmpv-dev:amd64 Depends on libmpv1:amd64 < 0.27.2-1ubuntu1 | 0.32.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umH > (= 0.32.0-1ubuntu1)
Broken libgmic1:amd64 Depends on libopencv-videoio4.2:amd64 < none | 4.2.0+dfsg-5 @un uH > (>= 4.2.0+dfsg)
Broken wine-stable-amd64:amd64 Depends on libfaudio0:amd64 < 19.07-0~bionic | 20.04-2 @ii umR >
Broken libqt4-opengl-dev:amd64 Depends on libqt4-dev:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
Broken phonon4qt5:amd64 Depends on phonon4qt5-backend-vlc:amd64 < 0.10.1-2 | 0.11.1-1build1 @ii umR >
Broken phonon4qt5:amd64 Depends on phonon4qt5-backend:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken geeqie:amd64 Depends on libffmpegthumbnailer4v5:amd64 < none | 2.1.1-0.2build2 @un uH >
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libkf5notifyconfig5:amd64 Depends on phonon4qt5:amd64 < 4:4.10.0-2 | 4:4.11.1-3build1 @ii umR >
Broken krita-gmic:amd64 Depends on libgmic1:amd64 < none | 2.4.5-1.1 @un uH > (= 2.4.5-1.1)
Broken k3b:amd64 Depends on libkf5notifyconfig5:amd64 < 5.44.0-0ubuntu1 | 5.68.0-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 4.96.0)
Broken wine-stable:amd64 Depends on wine-stable-amd64:amd64 < 5.0.2~bionic @ii mR > (= 5.0.2~bionic)
Broken winehq-stable:amd64 Depends on wine-stable:amd64 < 5.0.2~bionic @ii mR > (= 5.0.2~bionic)
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken winetricks:amd64 Depends on wine:amd64 < none | 5.0-3ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
Broken libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 Depends on libavcodec58:amd64 < none | 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 7:4.0)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I removed exfalso transcode k3b and that seems to have resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I removed exfalso transcode k3b and that seems to have resolved the issue

Comment: How did you determine that package to be the cause of the issue? Adding that to your answer could make it a lot more useful to other people.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove transcode k3b libk3b7-extracodecs.

I grepped /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log for everything that had "Broken" as part of the error, and started uninstalling packages from the bottom up, one at a time, until the upgrade calculation no longer failed.

There were still lots of "Broken libpython-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython2-dev:amd64...." references, but they no longer kept the upgrade from starting.